# view binding isn't working on Button setOnClickListner... [*ERROR = Variable 'getOTPButton' is never used] (KOTLIN)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

please check out this error. I have used view binding on this activity to save data in Firebase. I have used the If... else statement on setOnClickListner.

- Code for the Activity:

  class RegisterSelection : AppCompatActivity() {

  ```
       private lateinit var binding: ActivityRegisterSelectionBinding
       private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference

       @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
           binding = ActivityRegisterSelectionBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
           setContentView(binding.root)
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_selection)


           val checkPasswordTwo = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkPasswordTwo)
           val passwordText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.passwordText)
           val confirmPassText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.confirmPassText)
           val fullName=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.fullName).text.toString()
           val phoneNumberEdit=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.phoneNumberEdit).text.toString()
           val getOTPButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.getOTPButton)

           binding.getOTPButton.setOnClickListener {

               if(fullName.isEmpty() && phoneNumberEdit.isEmpty()){
                   Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Fill all the Fields!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
               }
               else{
                   database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UserDataClass")
                   val users = UserDataClass(fullName, phoneNumberEdit)
                   database.child(fullName).setValue(users).addOnSuccessListener {
                       binding.fullName.text.clear()
                       binding.phoneNumberEdit.text.clear()

                       Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Success!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                   }.addOnFailureListener {
                       Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Failed to Save!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                   }
                   val intent = Intent(this, getOTP::class.java)
                   startActivity(intent)

               }
           }

           checkPasswordTwo.setOnClickListener {
               if (checkPasswordTwo.text.toString() == "Show Password"){
                   passwordText.transformationMethod = HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance()
                   confirmPassText.transformationMethod = HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance()
                   checkPasswordTwo.text = "Hide Password"
               } else{
                   passwordText.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
                   confirmPassText.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
                   checkPasswordTwo.text = "Show Password"
               }
           }

       }

   }
  ```
- build.gradle

  `buildFeatures{ viewBinding true }`
- UserDataClass

  `data class UserDataClass(val fullName: String? = null, val phoneNumberEdit: String? = null)`

Output only shows the Toast "fill all the fields."
**Any suggestions would be grateful.**

Comment: You are saving off the field values outside the listener so they are always blank, even if the user changes the fields later. Move `val fullName=...` (and the other strings you get from `X.text.toString()`) inside the `setOnClickListener` method

Answer (score 0):

I recommend,`if(fullName.isEmpty() && phoneNumberEdit.isEmpty())` change this to `if(fullName.isEmpty() || phoneNumberEdit.isEmpty()){` - you want to ensure that both are filled I assume.
Secondly, since you are using `binding`, I would also recommend that you check for null this way: `binding.<edit text id>.text.isNullOrEmpty()`.
Lastly, it looks like you are initialising your text values by reading the text value in the edit text post inflation and **not** reading the values you have entered on button click. In your `onClickListener`, read the values from your `editText` and then check for null.